# How to convert a string to an integer using scala?

Tags: scala

Im having trouble with converting a string to an integer in scala. For example I have a program that requires the user to enter in a number "five", and multiply that by another int. However when I do that the number "five" is not holding any numerical value

Ive tried using an array of numbers

```
val num = Array("one", "two", "three")
val intValue:Int = num.indexOf("two") + 1
println(intValue)
```

Comment: I don't really understand what do You mean by the number "five" is not holding any value.

Comment: I am trying to get the number "five" to hold a numerical value

Comment: But what is "five" ? Is this a variable?

Comment: Yes. In a nutshell, because my code is too long to post, I have a shopping cart simulation. The user is to enter in the name, price and quantity of what they want to add to the cart. For the quantity, the code has to support a string input. For example: "name: shoes, quantity: five, price : 3" the total should be 15, but instead i am getting zero because quantity isn't holding the numerical value of "5"

Comment: Can't you directly specify a drop down for the quantity to take a number instead of s String? That way you can avoid alltogether this conversion.

Comment: Yes that would be much easier, but for the requirements of this I cant :(

Comment: Yea, so basically You need to create a `Map` with all Your possible quantities, so You can look it up.

Answer (score 3):

you can also create a map of key/value pairs and do look up.

```
val list = Map("five" -> 5,"six"->6)
list.get("five")
ans : Option[Int] = Some(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
variable match{
 case "one" => 1
 case "five" => 5
 case _ => 0
}
```

But you need to program every single case

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```scala
val num = Array("one", "two", "three")
val stringToInt = num.zipWithIndex.toMap.mapValues(_ + 1)
// Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3)

val two: Int = stringToInt("two")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using icu4j

```
libraryDependencies += "com.ibm.icu" % "icu4j" % "64.2"
```

```
val locale = new ULocale("En")
val formatter = new RuleBasedNumberFormat(locale, RuleBasedNumberFormat.SPELLOUT)
println(formatter.parse("fourteen"))
```

Output

```
14
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PartialFunction[String, Int] and lifting:

```
    val pf: PartialFunction[String, Int] = {
      case "one" => 1
      case "two" => 2
      case "three" => 3
    }

    pf.lift("two").foreach(println)
```